# Golang: Unmarshal JSON Object results in empty map

Tags: json, go

I've been stuck trying to unmarshal a json object.  I am not getting any errors but I am getting an empty map afterwards.  I'm new to go so I'm still trying to wrap my head around some of the language constructs.

Here is what my data source looks like

```
{ 
    "animationStates": {
        "idle": {
            "numFrames": 4,
            "frames": [
                {
                    "frame": {"x":43,"y":106,"w":12,"h":15},
                    "rotated": false
                },
                {
                    "frame": {"x":1,"y":143,"w":12,"h":14},
                    "rotated": false
                },
                {
                    "frame": {"x":71,"y":132,"w":12,"h":14},
                    "rotated": false
                },
                {
                    "frame": {"x":15,"y":126,"w":12,"h":15},
                    "rotated": true 
                }
            ]
        },
        "run": {
            "numFrames": 10,
            "frames": [
                {
                    "frame": {"x":73,"y":82,"w":12,"h":15},
                    "rotated": false
                },
                {
                    "frame": {"x":29,"y":125,"w":12,"h":15},
                    "rotated": false
                },
                {
                    "frame": {"x":33,"y":36,"w":12,"h":16},
                    "rotated": false
                },
                {
                    "frame": {"x":1,"y":107,"w":12,"h":16},
                    "rotated": false
                },
                {
                    "frame": {"x":1,"y":89,"w":12,"h":16},
                    "rotated": false
                },
                {
                    "frame": {"x":17,"y":54,"w":12,"h":16},
                    "rotated": false
                },
                {
                    "frame": {"x":1,"y":125,"w":12,"h":16},
                    "rotated": false
                }
                {
                    "frame": {"x":15,"y":143,"w":12,"h":14},
                    "rotated": false
                },
                {
                    "frame": {"x":29,"y":142,"w":12,"h":14},
                    "rotated": false
                },
                {
                    "frame": {"x":72,"y":99,"w":12,"h":15},
                    "rotated": false
                }
            ]
        },
        "roll": {
            "numFrames": 5,
            "frames": [
                {
                    "frame": {"x":71,"y":116,"w":12,"h":14},
                    "rotated": false
                },
                {
                    "frame": {"x":71,"y":148,"w":12,"h":10},
                    "rotated": false
                },
                {
                    "frame": {"x":73,"y":47,"w":12,"h":15},
                    "rotated": false
                },
                {
                    "frame": {"x":57,"y":147,"w":12,"h":11},
                    "rotated": false
                },
                {
                    "frame": {"x":29,"y":108,"w":12,"h":15},
                    "rotated": false
                }
            ]
        },
        "jump": {
            "numFrames": 1,
            "frames": [
                {
                    "frame": {"x":45,"y":54,"w":12,"h":16},
                    "rotated": false
                }
            ]
        },
        "fall": {
            "numFrames": 1,
            "frames": [
                {
                    "frame": {"x":29,"y":90,"w":12,"h":16},
                    "rotated": false
                }
            ]
        },
        "shoot": {
            "numFrames": 5,
            "frames": [
                {
                    "frame": {"x":37,"y":1,"w":14,"h":15},
                    "rotated": false
                },
                {
                    "frame": {"x":17,"y":37,"w":14,"h":15},
                    "rotated": false
                },
                {
                    "frame": {"x":1,"y":37,"w":14,"h":16},
                    "rotated": false
                },
                {
                    "frame": {"x":19,"y":19,"w":14,"h":15},
                    "rotated": false
                },
                {
                    "frame": {"x":1,"y":55,"w":14,"h":15},
                    "rotated": false
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the code that I'm using to unmarshal

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
)

type AnimationFrame struct {
    Frame struct {
        X int `json:"x"`
        Y int `json:"y"`
        W int `json:"w"`
        H int `json:"h"`
    } `json:"frame"`
    Rotated bool `json:"rotated"`
}

type Animation struct {
    NumFrames int `json:"numFrames"`
    Frames []AnimationFrame `json:"frames"` 
} 

type StateList struct {
    Actions map[string]Animation `json:"animationStates"`
}

func NewAnimation (file string) *StateList {
    list := make(map[string]Animation)
    s := &StateList{list}
    buff, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
    check(err)
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(buff), &s)
    return s 
}

func check (e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check and handle the error returned from `json.Unmarshal([]byte(buff), &s)`.  You will find that there's an invalid character '{' after array element at offset 1685.

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/xIIHcBOYzJ)

Comment: Thanks!  I wasn't sure how to check and handle that unmarshal.